# Windows Phone 8: Load/Create HTML on the fly and load into browser

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8

I am working on an app that reads XML and displays content accordingly with whats contained n the XML. Now i have the XML part done but i need one other part and that is to load a Small section of html code into a web browser element. Is there anyway for me to either dynamically create a html file (i was thinking maybe create one and save in storage then load from there?) or directly insert code into the web browser element.

Failing this i'll just create a php page on my server that adjusts according to value its passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your entire HTML code in a string variable and call the [NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method.

```
myWebBrowser.NavigateToString("myHTMLcode")
```

How you create the HTML string depends on your app but you could store a basic template and use `String.Replace` to replace any particular items in the code.